# SQL Server Case Statement bad performance

Tags: sql-server

I have a Query with multiple CASE statements as below. It is taking taking lot of time to execute even after proper Indexing. The Sum operation on case statements causing bad performance. How can I re write the above Query to improve performance.

```
SELECT H.Item,
       SUM(CASE A.CategeoryId
             WHEN 123 THEN NULLIF(IIF(C.IsActive = 0
                                      AND ( ( c.RowID IN ( 2, 4 )
                                              AND H.SubId <> ISNULL(C.ItemId, 0) )
                                             OR ( c.RowId NOT IN ( 2, 4 )
                                                  AND H.SubId = ISNULL(C.ItemId, 0) ) ), 0, A.Sales), 0)
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [TotalSales1],
       SUM(CASE A.CategeoryId
             WHEN 198 THEN NULLIF(IIF(C.IsActive = 0
                                      AND ( ( c.RowID IN ( 2, 4 )
                                              AND H.SubId <> ISNULL(C.ItemId, 0) )
                                             OR ( c.RowId NOT IN ( 2, 4 )
                                                  AND H.SubId = ISNULL(C.ItemId, 0) ) ), 0, A.Sales), 0)
             ELSE 0
           END) AS [TotalSales2],
       '',
       '',
       '',
       '',
       ''
FROM   SubItem AS H
       INNER JOIN Item AS C WITH (NOLOCK)
               ON H.Item = C.ItemId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp1 AS A
                    ON H.SubId = A.ItemId
WHERE  H.Productid = 99
GROUP  BY H.Item,
          C.ItemId,
          C.RowID
```

Comment: Post the execution plan. It won't be the `SUM` or `CASE` directly. Maybe your "proper Indexing" can be improved.

Comment: Perhaps `#temp1` is not indexed, temporary tables often get overlooked.

Comment: Rather than expecting us to *parse and understand* your intent from your query, can you describe, in words, *what you're trying to do*? Also, add *sample data* and *expected results*.